# Saving the output of a for loop in an array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, percentage

I am trying to write a custom script to monitor the disk usage space of "n" number of servers. I have two arrays, one array consists of the actual usage and the other array consists of the allowed limit. I would like to loop through the used storage array; determine the percentage, round it off to the nearest integer and output the same on the console to be later saved in an array.

I have the following piece of code that does this:

```
readarray -t percentage_storage_limit <<< "$(for ((j=0; j < ${#storage_usage_array[@]}; j++));    
    do $(awk "BEGIN {   
            ac=100*${storage_usage_array[$j]}/${storage_limit_array[$j]};    
            i=int(ac);   
            print (ac-i<0.5)?i:i+1    
         }");    
  done)";
```

The length of both storage_usage_array and storage_limit_array are the same. An index in storage_usage_array corresponds to the storage used on a server and an index on storage_limit_array corresponds to the limit on the same server.

Although the above statement runs as expected, I see a "command not found error" as follow, which is causing these output to not be saved in the "percentage_storage_limit" array.

```
8: command not found
4: command not found
```

am I missing something here? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you getting over-complicated syntax-wise. I would just accumulate the array within the for loop

```
percentage_storage_limit=()
for ((j=0; j < ${#storage_usage_array[@]}; j++)); do 
    percentage_storage_limit+=( $(
        awk -v u="${storage_usage_array[$j]}" -v l="${storage_limit_array[$j]}" '
            BEGIN {   
                ac = 100 * u / l
                i = int(ac)   
                print (ac-i < 0.5) ? i : i+1    
            }
        '
    ) )
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It helped a lot, but at line 7, why are you dividing val by itself?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work, is that whan you enclose awk in `$(...)` you tell bash to execute it's output, thus you want to execute `8` or `4` and bash errors to you that it didn't find such command. Just don't enclose awk in `$(...)`, you want to capture it's output, not execute it's output. And it would be better to use `< <(...)` then `<<<"$(...)"`:

```
readarray -t percentage_storage_limit < <(
    for ((j=0; j < ${#storage_usage_array[@]}; j++)); do
         awk "BEGIN {   
            ac=100*${storage_usage_array[$j]}/${storage_limit_array[$j]};    
            i=int(ac);   
            print (ac-i<0.5)?i:i+1    
         }";
    done
)
```

Anyway Glenn's answer shows the 'good' way to do this, without `readarray` call.